# In the Microsoft Debugger for Java extension for VSCode, is it possible to make it aware of Lombok?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, lombok

I'm trying to set up VSCode as a Java development environment for the Java project I'm working on at work. I've installed the recommended plugins for this listed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial), but my project uses Lombok to auto-generate getter and setter methods for beans. When I run the code in debug after successfully compiling it with Maven, I get errors on all the Bean objects that use Lombok in this way. The errors say that nothing uses the field, and that the field may not have been initialised. I've added the Lombok plug-in, but the debug plug-in seems unaware of the generated methods in the bytecode. Is there any way to make the Microsoft Java debugger plug-in aware of Lombok so that it doesn't put up these blocking errors when I'm trying to run a debug session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode is a bit of a new player in the java space, and we (the dev team behind Project Lombok) haven't looked at it yet.

I was looking around for precisely how VSCode works, and I found [these instructions](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Lombok-support) which should help you out.

I will put in some effort to create a doc page on projectlombok.org itself with these instructions.

Comment: Thanks - that looks pretty useful. I'll give that a go.

Comment: Update: Yeah, that seems to be set up already by the VSCode Lombok extension. I guess it must be something else - maybe I need to specify to the debugger that we need Lombok there too?